# How to set options of commands called by browser?

Tags: shell-script, browser, text-to-speech, spd-say, speech-dispatcher

Presently when [Speech Synthesis Markup Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-speech-synthesis11-20100907/) (SSML) is set as at `text` property of [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes) instance  at [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795371) or [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425523) web browsers the SSML is not parsed at *nix as reflected at audio output of [`speechSynthesis.speak()`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html#dfn-ttsspeak) call.

Browsing the source code of the browsers [`speech-dispatcher`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html) appears to be called by `.speak()` where either `spd-say` or [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/), if configured to do so, could be called by `speech-dispatcher`.

`spd-say` has an `x` option

```
-x, --ssml          Set SSML mode on (default: off)
```

`espeak` has an `m` option

```
-m     Interpret SSML markup, and ignore other < > tags
```

Have created a user configuration file for `speech-dispatcher` using

```
spd-conf -u
```

The documentation states that the user configuration file can be used to set parameters for specific clients

> **4.1.6 Parameter Settings Commands**
>
> The following parameter setting commands are available. For
>   configuration and history clients there are also functions for setting
>   the value for some other connection and for all connections. They are
>   listed separately below.
>
> C API function: `int spd_set_data_mode(SPDConnection *connection,
>   SPDDataMode mode)` Set Speech Dispatcher data mode. Currently, plain
>   text and SSML are supported. SSML is especially useful if you want to
>   use index marks or include changes of voice parameters in the text.
>
> mode is the requested data mode: `SPD_DATA_TEXT` or `SPD_DATA_SSML`.

Questions

1. How to set the default option of either or both `-x` for `spd-say` and `-m` for `espeak` commands at `~/.config/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf` for the clients Chromium and Firefox browsers when `.speak()` is called?
2. How to adjust the source code at [Chromium](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/speech-dispatcher/libspeechd.h?q=SSML&dr=CSs&l=171) and [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/webspeech/synth/speechd/SpeechDispatcherService.cpp#473) browsers to set the `-x` or `-m` options by default for the text set at `SpeechSpeechSynthesisUtterance` `text` property which is passed to `window.speechSynthesis.speak()`?

Comment: An alternative way that often works: Rename the binary/binaries, write a wrapper script that calls the binaries, and includes the options you want. Hacky, but possibly simpler. Another hacky way is to replace the name of the binary calls in the browser binary with the name of the wrapper script; this way you keep the standard names (but must redo this if you update your browser. Though it's scriptable with `dd` etc.)

Comment: @dirkt Can you post the possible alternatives that you are describing in at an answer?

Comment: This question is cross-posted at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991314/how-to-set-options-of-commands-called-by-browser). -1.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar What do you mean by "cross-posted"?

Comment: "Cross-posted": That the same question is already asked in one of the network sites, and would very well have gotten a good answer there. If it didn't, consider deleting the question there, or atleast updating that question with a link to the answer here, so that others having the same question may benefit.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar There is no answer at the question that you are referencing. The two sites are different.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way that often works: Rename the binary/binaries, write a wrapper script with the origina name that calls the renamed binaries, and includes the options you want. Hacky, but possibly simpler. (If you are not used to shell programming, look up `$*`).

Another hacky way is to replace the name of the binary calls in the browser binary with the name of the wrapper script; this way you keep the standard names.

The downside is that you must redo this if you update your browser, though it's scriptable with `grep` and `dd` along the lines of

```
grep -FobUa 'spd-say' browser_binary
echo -n 'spd-wrp' | dd bs=1 of=browser_binary seek=12345 conv=notrunc
```

where `spd-wrp` is the name of the wrapper script, and `12345` the position where grep found it. Use variations for multiple occurences etc. as appropriate for your binary.